# Is it possible to force a program that ignores signals to quit on ctrl-C?

Tags: shell-script, signals, sigint

I have a program that ignores SIGINT but that I want to run in the foreground. I would like to find a way to force it to close on Ctrl-C. Is there any way to write a wrapper (that you'd call `./wrapper.sh my_program`) that would force the misbehaving program to quit, potentially by detecting the ignored SIGINT and generating a SIGKILL?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21660539/3404377) is the exact opposite of what I am looking for -- I would like to force a program that ignores a signal to quit on SIGINT.

Comment: "by detecting the ignored SIGINT and generating a SIGKILL" -- Do you want the wrapper to actually confirm the SIGINT was ignored? or to assume it was ignored?

Comment: Be careful. Programs that ignore SIGINT usually do it for a very good reason. For kicks, start e.g. `vi(1)` in a terminal and send it a SIGKILL. A fun puzzle is to restore the terminal to usuability.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski It's fine if it assumes that SIGINT was ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's build a wrapper that "converts" SIGINT into SIGKILL.

We need a process that runs along `my_program` and gets SIGINT upon <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. When it receives SIGINT it should send SIGKILL to `my_program`. Note we don't need `my_program` to actually receive SIGINT caused by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>; it's enough it gets SIGKILL caused by the extra process.

Relevant facts:

- A standard way to run one process along another is to run one of them asynchronously in the background (i.e. with terminating `&`).
- When you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, it's your terminal emulator who sends SIGINT to processes in the foreground process group.
- Some (simple) shells run everything in the same process group. If they are told to run a command in the background then they will redirect its stdin to `/dev/null` or equivalent file to prevent the command from stealing input.
- Other shells can run each command in a separate process group. If they are told to run a command in the background then they will leave its stdin as-is; still the command in the background will not be able to steal input from the controlling terminal because of [`SIGTTIN`](http://curiousthing.org/sigttin-sigttou-deep-dive-linux). This allows the shell to move a job from the background to the foreground by informing the terminal of the new foreground process group. The mechanism is called job control and can be disabled. In scripts it's disabled by default.
- Either way a process in the background cannot read from the terminal. This means we shouldn't run `my_program` in the background in case the stdin is the terminal and `my_program` needs to read from it.
- Unfortunately in some shells we shouldn't run the other process in the background either. Some shells use separate process groups even when job control is disabled. The other process not being in the foreground process group will not receive SIGINT upon <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, so it won't be able to "convert" it to SIGKILL.
- In my Debian 10 `posh` is a shell that runs everything in the same process group.

This leads to the following wrapper:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env posh

( trap 'kill -s KILL 0' INT
  while kill -s 0 "$$" 2>/dev/null; do sleep 1; done
) &
exec "$@"
```

`exec "$@"` runs `my_program` (or whatever you specify), possibly with arguments. Thanks to `exec` `my_program` will replace the wrapper. Not only it will be able to read from the stdin which may be a terminal; its PID will be the one of the replaced wrapper. In this sense the wrapper is transparent. Additionally this has a nice feature: the PID of `my_program` is known before `my_program` starts and we can easily use it in the other process (in this case in a subshell in the background) to detect when `my_program` actually terminates.

The `trap` "converts" SIGINT into SIGKILL. Note `kill -s KILL 0` sends SIGKILL to the entire process group, including children of `my_program` if they are in the group (if you want to kill `my_program` only then use `kill -s KILL "$$"` instead). Nevertheless `kill -s 0 "$$"` tests the existence of `my_program` only.

There's an alternative that does not require a shell that runs everything in the same process group. The trick is: processes in a pipeline should run in one process group; and by clever redirecting you can build a pipeline where pieces are not connected to one another.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh -

exec 9>&1
( "$@"; kill -s TERM 0 ) >&9 9>&- | (
  trap 'kill -s KILL 0' INT
  while :; do sleep 1; done
)
```

In this variant `my_program` will not replace the wrapper. The second `kill` is to "convert" SIGINT to SIGKILL. The first `kill` is to terminate the loop in case `my_program` exits in circumstances when the loop would otherwise survive.

There are few scenarios that may not work as you expect (with any wrapper). Among them:

- If `my_program` forks and exit, leaving the real job to the child. The troublesome program in question most likely does not behave like this, since you tried to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> it. But in general it might.
- If `my_program` spawns child processes in another process group(s) and you'd like to kill them along with their parent.
- If `my_program` configures the terminal not to send SIGINT upon <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. If you suspect this happens then improve the wrapper by putting `stty -F /dev/tty intr ^C` between `sleep 1` and `done`. In this case the program may even not ignore SIGINT, it may simply make sure it won't get it from the terminal. So maybe SIGKILL is overkill; maybe it's enough to restore this functionality of the terminal and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> will start working.

From a comment:

> Programs that ignore SIGINT usually do it for a very good reason.

True. Try SIGTERM or SIGHUP instead of SIGKILL. Maybe the program in question does not ignore at least one of these and exits gracefully with proper cleanup.